# Topological data analysis and evaluating dimensionality reduction

Tags: references, dimensionality-reduction, unsupervised-learning, manifold-learning, topological-data-analysis

I did [an exploration](https://github.com/lambdaofgod/tda-project/blob/master/notebooks/Natural%20image%20patches.ipynb) some time ago on using TDA tools to see how topological features change after application of some nonlinear dimensionality reduction methods.

For example I found out that, for [Natural Image Patches](http://www.dam.brown.edu/ptg/REPORTS/01-3Rev.pdf) dataset, reducing dimension using Isomap seems to preserve persistent homology better than LLE or Kernel PCA (authors of [this paper](http://mii.stanford.edu/research/comptop/preprints/mumford.pdf) talk about Klein bottle, which is 2d manifold, so I tried embedding in 3d space).

**My question:**

Is there any research on that?

Comment: The link to "this paper" does not currently work.